# При отправке на почту пропадает разделитель строк

Tags: google-apps-script

При отправке на почту текста из ячейки Google таблицы убирается Разделитель строк (Enter).

То есть в ячейке текст выглядит:

1. Запись первая
2. Запись вторая

А на почту приходит:
1. Запись первая 2. Запись вторая

При работе с большими объемами текста неудобно.

Код выглядит так:

```
    var m3 = values[lastRow - 1][3];
    var body =  
            '<b>'+a3+'</b><br>'
                + m3 + '<br><br>';
```

**Как можно сохранить разделитель строк?**

Код:

```
for (var i = 1; i < lastRow2; i++) {
  // Logger.log(i);

  var found = false;
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow(); // последний ряд

  for (; lastRow > 2; lastRow--) {
    // Идём с последнего ряда, пока даты = вчера

    if (
      Utilities.formatDate(values[lastRow - 1][0], 'GMT+3', 'dd.MM.yyyy') ==
      yesterday
    ) {
      // заголовки
      var a1 = values[0][1];
      var a2 = values[0][2];
      var a3 = values[0][3];
      var a4 = values[0][4];
      // var a5 = values[0][5];

      // значения
      var date = values[lastRow - 1][0]; // Дата
      // yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'
      date = Utilities.formatDate(date, 'GMT+3', 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm');
      var m1 = values[lastRow - 1][1]; // Email
      var m2 = values[lastRow - 1][2]; // Оценка дня
      var m3 = values[lastRow - 1][3]; // Что сделано
      var m4 = values[lastRow - 1][4]; // Что нужно сделать

      if (values2[i][0] == m1) {
        var found = true;
        // Logger.log(" Found: "+values2[i][0]);

        var m6 = values2[i][1]; // Имя
        // Logger.log(" " + i + " email= "+m1+"; Name= " + m6);

        var name = m6;
        var replyTo = m1;
        var subject = '' + m6 + ' ' + date;
        var body =
          '<b>' +
          a2 +
          '</b><br>' +
          m2 +
          '<br><br>' +
          '<b>' +
          a3 +
          '</b><br>' +
          '\n' +
          m3 +
          '<br><br>' +
          '<b>' +
          a4 +
          '</b><br>' +
          m4 +
          '<br><br>';

        var wheretosend = values2[i][2];

        if (wheretosend != '') {
          var recipients = wheretosend;

          MailApp.sendEmail({
            to: recipients,
            cc: replyTo,
            subject: subject,
            htmlBody: body,
            name: 'Итоги дня',
            replyTo: replyTo
          });
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте в параметры письма ключ `htmlBody`

```
MailApp.sendEmail({
  to: "recipient@example.com",
  subject: "Logos",
  htmlBody: '<b>' + a3 + '</b><br>' + m3 + '<br><br>'
});
```

Или сделайте вашему `body` мультилайн

```
  var body = a3 + '\n' + m3;
```

Проверенные примеры

```
function sendMessage() {
  var s1 = 'строка 1';
  var s2 = 'строка 2';

  var body = [s1, s2].join('<br>');
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: 'test@test.test',
    subject: 'test body message',
    body: body
  });
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
function sendMessageHtml() {
  var s1 = 'строка 1';
  var s2 = 'строка 2';

  var htmlBody = [s1, s2].join('\n');
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: 'test@test.test',
    subject: 'test htmlbody message',
    htmlBody: htmlBody
  });
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
function t() {
  var a2 = 'string a2';
  var a3 = 'string a3';
  var m2 = 'string m2';
  var m3 = 'string m3';

  var body =
    '<b>' +
    a2 +
    '</b><br>' +
    m2 +
    '<br><br>' +
    '<b>' +
    a3 +
    '</b><br>' +
    '\n' +
    m3;
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: 'test@test.test',
    subject: 'test htmlbody message',
    htmlBody: body
  });
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Первый вариант: у меня уже так и было сделано изначально

Comment: Добавьте кода, ничего не понятно. У меня работает.

Comment: Да, добавил в текст вопроса.

Comment: Второй вариант я попробовал - но тоже не получилось

Comment: Привел все примеры. Добавил, насколько это возможно, ваш пример. Добавил скрины. Ваша проблема не повторяется.